# Configuring multiple XFS filesystems with external logs on LVM

Tags: raid, lvm, xfs

I'm configuring an NFS server with multiple filesystems for use by different groups of users. Other similar systems we have installed recently have used XFS filesystems on logical volumes, on top of RAID 6, so that we can leave some free space and add or expand filesystems as required.

In order to improve write performance I am considering using external logs for the XFS filesystems this time, on the separate RAID 1 pair that houses the OS. Presumably this means I need an extra partition for each filesystem. The obvious way to do this is to put these on logical volumes too. Is there any reason not to do this?